# How to interact, drag and resize the shapes drawn on canvas?

Tags: flutter

I am able to draw shapes. But I am not able to select a particular shape and perform actions like drag.

```
class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  //This class is use to paint the image on canvas
  final ui.Image image;

  ImagePainter({
    required this.image,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class AnotationPainter extends CustomPainter {
  //This class is use to paint the shapes on canvas
  final List anotations;
  final Color color;

  AnotationPainter({
    required this.anotations,
    required this.color,
  });

  List getWidthHeight(points) {
    double width = 0.0;
    double height = 0.0;
    if (points[0].dx > points[1].dx) {
      width = points[0].dx - points[1].dx;
    } else {
      width = points[1].dx - points[0].dx;
    }
    if (points[0].dy > points[1].dy) {
      height = points[0].dy - points[1].dy;
    } else {
      height = points[1].dy - points[0].dy;
    }

    return [width, height];
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final linePaint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

    final circlePaint = Paint()
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..color = color;

    final rectanglePaint = Paint()
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..color = color;
    for (Annotation anotation in anotations) {
      if (anotation.visible) {
        if (anotation.type == 'line') {
          canvas.drawLine(anotation.points[0], anotation.points[1], linePaint);
        }
        if (anotation.type == 'rect') {
          final matrix = getWidthHeight(anotation.points);
          canvas.drawRect(
            anotation.points[0] & Size(matrix[0], matrix[1]),
            rectanglePaint,
          );
        }
        if (anotation.type == 'circle') {
          final matrix = getWidthHeight(anotation.points);
          canvas.drawArc(
            anotation.points[0] & Size(matrix[0], matrix[1]),
            ((matrix[0] * matrix[0]) +
                (matrix[1] + matrix[1]) / (2 * matrix[1])),
            7,
            false,
            circlePaint,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}


class Annotation {
  
  bool visible;
  List<Offset> points;
  String type;
  String text;

  Annotation({
    required this.visible,
    required this.points,
    required this.type,
    required this.text,
  });

  void updateTo(Offset to) {
    points[1] = to;
  }
}

SizedBox(


width: image!.width.toDouble(),
  height: image!.height.toDouble(),
  child: Builder(
    builder: (ctx) => GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: (details) {
        RenderBox renderBox = ctx.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        setState(() {
          images[selectedImage]['annotations'].add(
            Annotation(
              visible: true,
              type: annotationType,
              points: [
                renderBox.globalToLocal(
                  details.globalPosition,
                ),
                renderBox.globalToLocal(
                  details.globalPosition,
                ),
              ],
              text: '',
            ),
          );
        });
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        RenderBox renderBox = ctx.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        setState(() {
          images[selectedImage]['annotations']
                  [images[selectedImage]['annotations'].length - 1]
              .updateTo(renderBox.globalToLocal(
            details.globalPosition,
          ));
        });
      },
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: ImagePainter(
          image: image!,
        ),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: AnotationPainter(
            anotations:
                images[selectedImage]
                    ['annotations'],
            color: Theme.of(context)
                .primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

- ImagePaiter class which is use to draw image on canvas.
- AnotationPainter class which is use to draw shapes like line, circle, rectangle.
- Annotation class which is user defined data structure.
- SizedBox which has GestureDetector and CustomPaint to render image and shapes

Comment: Hello first of all please share your code what you have tried so far, After reading your quesion what i understand is you want to drag and resize on pich etc right?

Comment: If using canvas, the individual elements drawn are not DOM elements. canvas is just a pixel buffer. Only way would be to do your own hit detection, track all the objects yourself, handle all mouse clicks and moves, etc.